# Could not lock surface Error

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas, samsung-mobile, illegalargumentexception

I am experiencing strange crash for Samsung Galaxy Core GT I8262. Any activity that i select as a launch activity gives this error after few secs. This results is phone get restarted again and again. When i uninstall my app, the restarting stops. I have looked around but couldnt find any concrete solution. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am guessing this issue can only be fixed in AndroidManifest.xml. Please note I am not using any SurfaceView.

```
D/OpenGLRenderer(383): Enabling debug mode 0

E / SurfaceTextureClient(25082): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
W / Adreno200 - EGLSUB(25082): < DequeueBuffer: 420 > : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device
W / Adreno200 - EGLSUB(25082): < DequeueBuffer: 420 > : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device
W / Adreno200 - EGLSUB(25082): < DequeueBuffer: 420 > : dequeue native buffer fail: No such device
W / Adreno200 - EGL(25082): < eglSurfaceResize: 3570 > : EGL_BAD_ALLOC
W / HardwareRenderer(25082): EGL error: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
W / HardwareRenderer(25082): Mountain View, we 've had a problem here. Switching back to software rendering.
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): Could not lock surface
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java: 88)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java: 2354)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java: 2317)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java: 2185)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java: 1993)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java: 1143)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java: 4674)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java: 725)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java: 555)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java: 525)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java: 711)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 615)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 92)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 137)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 4960)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1038)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 805)
E / ViewRootImpl(25082): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this issue. The crash log is no way related to the issue. I was setting a non existent SyncInterval, which was causing this crash.

Good luck of anyone encounters this issue :)